# Strange effect of passing parameter as `const`

Tags: c++, inheritance, parameters, sfml

Consider the following classes :

1. Bullet class

```cpp
    class Bullet : public sf::Drawable {
    public:
        Bullet(const sf::Vector2f& pos, const sf::Vector2f& dir, 
            const float& speed, const float& time, const float& life_time);
        ~Bullet();
        
        bool collides(const Wall &wall);
    private:
        ...
}
```

and Wall class

```cpp
    class Wall : public sf::Drawable {
    public:
        Wall(const sf::Vector2f & endpoint1, const sf::Vector2f& endpoint2);
        void sample();
        ~Wall();
    private:
          ...
}
```

For some reason, that I can't entirely comprehend, I can not call any methods for the `wall` parameter of the `bool collides(const Wall &wall)` method, when the `const` is present, e.g. if I remove the const, everything works just fine.

I think it might have something to do with inheriting the `sf::Drawable`, but I am not that experienced with SFML yet.

Can somebody clarify what should I look into to find what is causing this?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can only call `const` methods on `const` objects. If `collides` doesn't change internal state of `Bullet`, you should declare (and define) it like this: `bool collides(const Wall &wall) const;` I suppose there is a duplicate somewhere, will try to find something

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Thank you very much, completely forgot about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot call an non-const member function on a `const` object or a *reference to* a `const` object, simple as that.

```
class Wall : public sf::Drawable {
public:
    void sample() const; // <---- you need this
};
```

Now it's up to you, either you make member functions that don't change the state be `const`, or get rid of constness of the parameter of `collides`.